# How do I create a NuGet package with an interop dll for .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a COM Interop dll that I can use in projects targeting .NET Framework 4.8, by adding a reference to the dll. This works fine. Now, I'm trying to create a NuGet package which I can use instead of adding a reference to the dll.

I create the NuGet package like this: I have a folder containing four things:

- interopFileName.dll
- Package.nuspec
- Package.targets
- nuget.exe

The nuspec file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Package</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Very descriptive description</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="interopFileName.dll" target="build"/>
    <file src="Package.targets" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I run `nuget pack`, and a .nupkg file is created.
If I install this package in a project targeting .NET Standard 2.0, I get the warning below, but everything seems to work fine. I can use the package in the project.

```
Warning NU1701  Package 'Package 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, 
NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1'
instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Now, if I try to install it in a project targeting .NET Framework 4.8 I get the following error

```
Error       Could not install package 'Package 1.0.0'.
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8',
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

So it looks like the warning above says that the package should be used in .NET Framework projects, but that does not work, while using it in a .NET Standard 2.0 project does work. Could someone explain this to me, and help me understand how I should create the package so that it can be used in a .NET Framework project?

Comment: target="build" should only be used for MSBuild .props and .targets files.